# Android CI/CD pipeline on AWS

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, sdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am following this [AWS Android CI/CD pipeline guide](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/automatically-build-your-android-app-with-aws-codebuild/). It builds is successfully, but artifacts are not uploaded on S3.

My **buildspec.yml**:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - ./gradlew assembleDebug
artifacts:
  files:
    - app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
```

**Error**:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2m 1s
30 actionable tasks: 30 executed
[Container] 2021/04/26 11:36:29 Phase complete: BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2021/04/26 11:36:29 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2021/04/26 11:36:29 Entering phase POST_BUILD
[Container] 2021/04/26 11:36:29 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2021/04/26 11:36:29 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2021/04/26 11:36:30 Expanding base directory path: .
[Container] 2021/04/26 11:36:30 Assembling file list
[Container] 2021/04/26 11:36:30 Expanding .
[Container] 2021/04/26 11:36:30 Expanding file paths for base directory .
[Container] 2021/04/26 11:36:30 Assembling file list
[Container] 2021/04/26 11:36:30 Expanding app/build/outputs/
[Container] 2021/04/26 11:36:30 Phase complete: UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS State: FAILED
[Container] 2021/04/26 11:36:30 Phase context status code: CLIENT_ERROR Message: no matching artifact paths found
```

I have created the S3 bucket and add the bucket name and path like below screenshot. [image: AWS S3 Artifact]

**Bucket permission**:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1619425519087",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1619425507980",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::816888571071:user/salahuddin"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::chiragh-andriod"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the build location correct? I see `[Container] 2021/04/26 11:36:30 Expanding app/build/outputs/` in the output of the Build pipeline whereas artifacts are referencing `app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk`. If you want to know the path to this location, you can run `$CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR` during a build.

Comment: I have configure the Android pipeline in codebuild step with below mentioned buildspec.yml ```version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    run-as: root
    commands:
      - apt update
  build:
    run-as: root
    commands:
      - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=$(pwd)/.gradle
      - chmod +x ./gradlew
      - fastlane beta
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
```  Also I have successfully uploaded the .apk on google playstore using the docker image vratislav/gitlab-ci-fastlane-android
inside of codebuild env. this docker image have already ruby and fastlane installed